# localStorage.set и $('body').html()

Tags: html, dom, localstorage

Хочу записать результат `$('body').html()` в `localStorage`. Как сделать так, чтобы результат не содержал javascript-код и записывал только элементы страницы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Клонируем <body/>
var $cloneBody = $('body').clone();

// Удаляем все теги script
$cloneBody.find('script').remove();


// Выводим в консоль, чтоб убедиться, что нет тегов script
console.log($cloneBody.html());

// Сохраняем в localStorage
localStorage.setItem('key', $cloneBody.html());
```

Comment: А не могли бы подсказать как корректно проверить существует ли скрипт на странице.
Пока я делаю примерно так " Если нет скрипта с ID то создаю скрипт" 
Всё ок в броузере возвращается 304, НО если перезагружать словно безумный страницу то будут сыпаться ошибки(т.е. не успевают прогружаться скрипты)
Пробовал там же в create добавлять myscript.async = 'false' Не помогает :(

А так благодарен вам, но моя проблема окончательно не решена )

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю контекст проблемы, ибо тут каким-то образом затесался статут ответа 304, хотя речь было о работе с DOM. Поясните какой вы скрипт создаете и в результате чего появляется ответ со статусом 304

Comment: Давай по порядку:
-вы дали для меня верный ответ, он подходит.
-Но как с этим решением выявилось, что всё таки нужно оставлять некоторые скрипты, чтобы при смене 'body' оставались в памяти браузера скрипты js.
-В связи с этим я сделал проверку, если есть скрипт(нахожу по ID) то при смене 'body' не выполняется скрипт(один и тот же) и возвращается статус 304(т.е. возвращено из кеша браузера что экономит ресурсы)
-Хорошо. Сказал себе и начал тестировать и при многократном рефреше (F5) странички я обнаруживаю ошибки(означающие что скрипты не загрузились)

Comment: А что у вас при после рефреша страницы происходит?

Comment: возвращается главная страница index.php без работающего jQquery
Дело в том, что если я ставлю проверку на наличие скрипта, при рефреше я получаю уведомление 304 и тут двоякая ситуация и возникает если безумно рефрешать то ошибка вылетает jQuery is not defined, а если рефрешнуть чуть погодя то всё работает...

Comment: Я слабо понимаю ситуацию последующим после загрузки страницы. И так, у вас загружается index.php который отдает html, в котором нет подключения jQuery. Далее, я не понимаю о какой проверки скрипта речь? Что за проверка? Какой скрипт проверяет? И как собственно проверка скрипта связана с рефрешом с 304 статусом?